# Adding items to tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Iv'e seen the following graph at Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS third edition (P. 596) and I wanted to create it with latex code instead of copying it (the main purpose is the option to edit it and use it for other graphs). I know how to create the nodes, labels of nodes and the numbers inside nodes.

What I don't know is how to add the label (a) at left side and the items at right side (Q and the square contains s with 0 beneath it [I know how to create square node with label and character inside]).

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is the code which I use to create the graph (I'm using lyx and the preamble is configured correctly):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance=2.5cm,main node/.style={minimum size=.7cm,circle,fill=white!20,draw}, 
    scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
    \node[main node] [label={270:$v$}] (A) {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (B) [above of=A,label=$r$] {$\infty$};
    \node[minimum size=.7cm,circle,fill=lightgray,draw] (C) [right of=B,label=$s$]{$0$}; 
    \node[main node] (D) [below of=C,label={270:$w$}] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (E) [right of=D,label={270:$x$}] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (F) [right of=E,label={270:$y$}] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (G) [above of=F,label=$u$] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (H) [left of=G,label=$t$] {$\infty$};
    \draw (A) -> (B) -> (C) -> (D) -> (E) -> (F) -> (G) -> (H);
    \draw (D) -> (H) -> (E) -> (G);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know that my code might be pretty ugly and could be better, I'm still a learner and any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a label.  You can add text to any side of a node by adding another node (text only).  You can create a multiline text entry inside a node by using \parbox, [text width=...], \tabuilar, minipage, \savebox, etc.

Comment: Where is the operation `->` in the pgfmanual ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods you could use to position nodes at those locations. Below I've placed them relative to the `current bounding box` node, and also showed another way (commented) using the two outermost nodes that you've defined already.

Note that to draw a line between two coordinates one should use `--` not `->`, e.g.  `(a) -- (b)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [node distance=2.5cm,main node/.style={minimum size=.7cm,circle,fill=white!20,draw}, 
    scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
    \node[main node] [label={270:$v$}] (A) {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (B) [above of=A,label=$r$] {$\infty$};
    \node[minimum size=.7cm,circle,fill=lightgray,draw] (C) [right of=B,label=$s$]{$0$}; 
    \node[main node] (D) [below of=C,label={270:$w$}] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (E) [right of=D,label={270:$x$}] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (F) [right of=E,label={270:$y$}] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (G) [above of=F,label=$u$] {$\infty$};
    \node[main node] (H) [left of=G,label=$t$] {$\infty$};
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- (H);
    \draw (D) -- (H) -- (E) -- (G);

    \node at ([xshift=-0.6cm]current bounding box.west) {(a)};
% alternative method:
%    \path (A) -- node[left=0.5cm] {(a)} (B);

    \node at ([xshift=1.5cm]current bounding box.east) [fill=lightgray,draw=black,inner sep=7pt,label=left:$Q$,label=below:$0$] {$s$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the first time I see `->` . Where is this option in the pgfmanual ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes It's from the OPs code, I didn't notice it. I've never seen it either, will edit to `--`.

Comment: thanks. It's used in a graph but it's not the case here ... strange because this operation is accepted

Comment: @AlainMatthes Yes, I was a bit surprised that it worked myself.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Actually, I solved it myself in a bit different way. Should I edit my first post?

Comment: @Galc127 Add an answer of your own instead.

Comment: @AlainMatthes It's a "feature" of TikZ parser: you may use `-<`, `-a` or any character after `-` except `|` and TikZ interprets this sequence as `--`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks Paul Good to know, but I think that it's not a good idea to use this "feature".